# How to sum before average in a Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a big report that contains the following columns:

timestamp,hostname,type,count

I have a line every 5 minutes for each node that represents the transaction the node managed, both of type "success" and "failure". This value is collected for many weeks and added to the file.

I want to see the average number of failures (or success) *on the global cluster* per hour (rows) and weekday (columns).

I added the =hour(timestamp) and =weekday(timestamp) columns and I put them in the rows and columns respectively of a pivot table, also the type is added as a filter.

But I'm not able to summarize (might not be the most appropriate English word) the value counting *the sum* of all the nodes as a single value. If I add count to the values section of the pivot table and chose average as the aggregation function it gives me the average *per node* and that is not what I need!

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please share some (dummy) data in your question and the expected result with that. You could use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to create a table you can post here.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your requirement?

Comment: I posted some sample data here: https://pastebin.com/bbsX4hg6


These two images explain what I want to do: https://imgur.com/a/gcJUWSb


In the second image there is the column "totalsum_value" and that is simply the sum of all integer values for the same type, same timestamp, ignoring the Resource. 


Hope this clarifies.